# Is possible to detect a continuous LONG PRESS onto a 2nd activity?

Tags: android

My question is whether it is possible to detect a long press on the second activity that is launch.

The long press on the first activity brings me to the second activity but i want to detect the long press at the 2nd activity as well

Answer (score 0):

No, you have that as when new Activity opens, you need to to start press again to make it registered (having finger already down does not count). But you can pass information to second activity about long press (in. i.e. Bundle) if this information is useful for any reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would ask if using a fragment or dialog can solve this issue?

Comment: No, it won't change a thing.